# APNs Production iOS and p12 file

Tags: ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program

My client has a p12 file created by a previous developer. He had used it to create the main developer certificate of the client and others certificates like APNS.

Now I need to create a new APNs Production iOS certificate for the application I'm writing, my doubts are:

1) When I'm asked to upload a CSR (check the screenshot) can I create a new CSR through the KeyChain with my data or It would be better to start from the p12 from the client?

[image]

2) Does using a new CSR involves problem/error since the previous developer has signed the main dev certificate with different data?

3) Is there a way to create a CSR starting from a p12?

Answer (score 1):

**Goto -> Keychain** and follow the image

[image]